# Json to XML using ruby

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails, xml

I'm converting the Json to XML in ruby using .to_xml conversion
as part of xml tag getting '-' instead of '_'.

```
JSON used: 

{
  "Test_xml": {
    "user_Details": {
      "UserName": "abcd",
      "Password": 1234
    }
  }
}


Expected XML:

<Test_xml>
    <user_Details>
        <UserName>abcd</UserName>
        <Password>1234</Password>
    </user_Details>
</Test_xml>



But got this as XML:

<Test-xml>
    <user-Details>
        <UserName>abcd</UserName>
        <Password>1234</Password>
    </user_Details>
</Test-xml>
```

In above case instead of _ we are receiving - as part of xml tag

Comment: You need to show the input JSON and the output XML. As a general point, every JSON to XML conversion library produces a different answer: they all solve the same problems in different ways. If you're fussy about the exact XML you want to produce, you typically need to either (a) do the conversion by hand, or (b) post-process the result with XSLT.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.